# Find parent div and add class

Tags: jquery

Looking for some help here getting `.parent()` and `.find()` working for me... I have a series of DIVs on the page as per below chunk of code. What I want is that when a user rolls over the `.linkerBtn` an `href` that I add a new class to the top level parent `threeCol` Div called `newsFeedItemHovered` - please help!

```
<div class="threeCol">
  <div class="threeColInner">
    <div class="feedItemWrapper newsFeedItem noBottom">
      <h3>
        <a title="News article 3" href="news-and-events/latest-news/news-article-3.html">News article 3</a>
      </h3>
      <p class="ItemStamp">03/09/2015</p>
      <p>News post summary text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer euismod euismod euismod. Quisque cursus quam sem, ac fermentum quam molestie in.</p>
      <p class="noBottom">
        <a class="linkerBtn inline small" title="Read more about News article 3" href="news-and-events/latest-news/news-article-3.html">Read more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so on your mouse over event do something like this: $(this).closest('div').addClass('classname');

Comment: `$(this).parents('.threeCol').addClass('...');` also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("a.linkerBtn").hover(function() {
  // Add class while hovered over anchor
  $(this).closest(".threeCol").addClass("newsFeedItemHovered");
}, function() {
  // Remove class when we move away
  $(this).closest(".threeCol").removeClass("newsFeedItemHovered");
});
```

```css
.newsFeedItemHovered {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="threeCol">
  <div class="threeColInner">
    <div class="feedItemWrapper newsFeedItem noBottom">
      <h3><a title="News article 3" href="news-and-events/latest-news/news-article-3.html">News article 3</a></h3>
      <p class="ItemStamp">03/09/2015</p>
      <p>News post summary text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer euismod euismod euismod. Quisque cursus quam sem, ac fermentum quam molestie in.</p>
      <p class="noBottom"><a class="linkerBtn inline small" title="Read more about News article 3" href="news-and-events/latest-news/news-article-3.html">Read more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="threeCol">
  <div class="threeColInner">
    <div class="feedItemWrapper newsFeedItem noBottom">
      <h3><a title="News article 3" href="news-and-events/latest-news/news-article-3.html">News article 3</a></h3>
      <p class="ItemStamp">03/09/2015</p>
      <p>News post summary text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer euismod euismod euismod. Quisque cursus quam sem, ac fermentum quam molestie in.</p>
      <p class="noBottom"><a class="linkerBtn inline small" title="Read more about News article 3" href="news-and-events/latest-news/news-article-3.html">Read more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```